# CNN Pytorch: what parameters to use when creating my own model?

Tags: python, pytorch, classification, conv-neural-network

I am new in this field; I have to create a CNN by pulling my model.

I want to develop a network that categorizes car images using [this dataset](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Ejkrause/cars/car_dataset.html) (8144 train images, 8041 test images, 196 different classes). To start getting used to it, I began using ResNet18, and now I wanted to create my model.

I have followed what is written [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598012/cnn-pytorch-how-are-parameters-selected-and-flow-between-layers), but I am having difficulty in choosing the correct parameters and hyperparameters anyway, I do not understand based on what these values  (YY in code) ​​are determined. I resized all my images at 3x224x224.

This is my code so far:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models

imagenet_stats = ([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

train_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
                                 transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                 transforms.RandomRotation(15),
                                 transforms.ToTensor(),
                                 transforms.Normalize(*imagenet_stats,inplace=True)
                                ])
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(train_O, transform=train_tfms)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

test_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize(*imagenet_stats,inplace=True), 
                               ])
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(test_O, transform=test_tfms)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(3, 224, kernel_size=15, padding=7)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
        self.hidden= nn.Linear(224*112*112, 128)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.out = nn.Linear(128, 196)
        self.act = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.act(self.conv(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.act(self.hidden(x))
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x

net_train = Net()
```

Comment: Hi Nicoloda, and welcome on SO! I'm affraid this question doesn't fit on StackOverflow as well as being too broad. What you're asking here is:  how to choose my layer's hyper-parameters. Also, adding `YY` on `padding` in your snippet tells me you should take a deeper look at what Conv2D does before going straight using a network of that size. I suggest you try with smaller network and a simpler task (and dataset). This way you can experiment with different params, changing the architecture and adding dropouts, etc...

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but unfortunately I need to work on this dataset. I know that the padding refers to zero padding, but I do not know how the value is connected to the Conv2d call, I left it "blank" on purpose.

Comment: "I do not know how the value is connected to the `Conv2d` call", well based on the value you provide on the initial call (num of input/output layers, padding, stride, kernel size), the layer will be initialized with the correct amount of parameters. Then in your `forward` you can your instance of `Conv2d` with an input vector. Tell me what's bothering you exactly?

Comment: @Ivan, I edited the code using a simpler custom Net. I tried inserting the value, I used a filter approximately 1/16 smaller than my input, and added a padding so that the size won't change. But when I try to run it, it does not run because it says:

`mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x2860256 and 2809856x128)`

Comment: Works fine for me. What is the shape of your input tensor? The error must be in your complete model then. Can you provide the parameters for the other `Conv2d`'s?